# telegraf how to check if user is admin?

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram-bot, telegraf

i have this code:

```
function isAdmin(idOfChat, IdOfUser, ctx) {
  //function
  return isAdminBoolean
}
bot.command("test", ctx => {
  if (isAdmin(ctx.message.chat.id, ctx.message.from.id) == true) {
    ctx.reply("Admin")
  }else{
    ctx.reply("._.")
  }
})
```

how to make it work?

sorry for my bad English)))

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write your method as a promise (because Telegraf queries from Telegram API, so, your isAdmin method could be like this)

```
function isAdmin(idOfChat, IdOfUser, ctx) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       //Get user information first
       ctx.telegram.getChatMember(idOfChat, IdOfUser).then((user) => {
           //Then check if user is admin (or creator)
           resolve(user.status == "administrator" || user.status == "creator");
       })
       .catch((error) => {
            //Reject if it's an error
            reject(error);
       });
   });
}
```

Then, for use it into your main function, you should have to handle it like this:

```
bot.command("test", ctx => {
   isAdmin(ctx.message.chat.id, ctx.message.from.id, ctx).then((result) => {
       if (result) {
           ctx.reply("Admin");
       } else {
           ctx.reply("._.");
       }
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     ctx.reply("An error has ocurred trying to get user rank: " + JSON.stringify(error));
   });
});
```